# Transform array of nested Hashes into flat array of non-nested hashes

Tags: ruby

I want to transform the given array into result array:

```
given = [{
  "foo_v1_4" => [{
    "derivate_version" => 0,
    "layers" => {
      "tlayer" => {
        "baz" => {
          "three" => 0.65
        },
        "bazbar" => {
          "three" => 0.65
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}]


# the value of key :one is first hash key (foo_v1_4) plus underscore (_) plus derivate_version (0)
result = [{
    one: 'foo_v1_4_0',
    tlayer: 'baz',
    three: '0.6'
  },
  {
    one: 'foo_v1_4_0',
    tlayer: 'bazbar',
    three: '0.6'
  }
]
```

What I tried:

```
given.each do |el |

    el.each do |derivat |
      derivat.each do |d |
        d.each do |layer |
          layer.each do |l |
            derivat = "#{d}_#{l['derivate_version']}"
          puts derivat
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I'm struggling at iterating through "layers" hash, the amount of elements in layers is equal to the amount of elements in result array.

Comment: Your post is already tagged with ruby so there's no need to have "Ruby: " in your post title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to format the objects so we can better see their structures:

```
given = [
  {
    "foo_v1_4" => [
      { "derivate_version" => 0,
        "layers" => {
          "tlayer" => {
            "baz" => { "three" => 0.65 },
            "bazbar" => { "three" => 0.65 }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
result = [
  {
    one: 'foo_v1_4_0',
    tlayer: 'baz',
    three: '0.6'
  },
  {
    one: 'foo_v1_4_0',
    tlayer: 'bazbar',
    three: '0.6'
  }
]
```

We can begin by writing the structure of `result`:

```
result = [
  {
    one: 
    tlayer:
    three:
  },
  {
    one: 
    tlayer:
    three:
  }
]
```

We see that

```
given = [ { "foo_v1_4" => <array> } ]
```

The values of the keys `:one` in the hash `result[0]` is therefore the first key of the first element of `given`:

```
one_val = given[0].keys[0] 
  #=> "foo_v1_4"

result = [
  {
    one: one_val
    tlayer:
    three:
  },
  {
    one: one_val
    tlayer:
    three:
  }
]
```

All the remaining objects of interest are contained in the hash

```
h = given[0]["foo_v1_4"][0]["layers"]["layer"]
  #=> {
  #     "baz"=>{ "three"=>0.65 },
  #     "bazbar"=>{ "three"=>0.65 }
  #   }
```

so it is convenient to define it. We see that:

```
h.keys[0]
  #=> "baz"
h.keys[1]
  #=> "bazaar"
h["bazbar"]["three"]
  #=> 0.65
```

Note that it generally is not good practice to assume that hash keys are ordered in a particular way.

We may now complete the construction of `result`,

```
v = h["bazbar"]["three"].truncate(1)
  #=> 0.6

result = [
  {
    one: one_val,
    tlayer: h.keys[0],
    three: v
  },
  { one: one_val,
    tlayer: h.keys[1],
    three: v
  }
]
  #=> [
  #     { :one=>"foo_v1_4", :tlayer=>"baz",    :three=>0.6 },
  #     { :one=>"foo_v1_4", :tlayer=>"bazbar", :three=>0.6 }
  #   ]
```

The creation of the temporary objects `one_val`, `h`, and `v` improves time- and space-efficiency, makes the calculations easier to test and improves the readability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
result = []
given.each do |level1|
  level1.each do |key, derivate_versions|
    derivate_versions.each do |layers|
      # iterate over the elements under tlayer
      layers.dig('layers', 'tlayer').each do |tlayer_key, tlayer_value|
        sub_result = {}
        # key - foo_v1_4, layers['derivate_version'] - 0 => 'foo_v1_4_0'
        sub_result[:one] = key + '_' +  layers['derivate_version'].to_s
        # talyer_key - baz, barbaz
        sub_result[:tlayer] = tlayer_key
        # talyer_value - { "three" => 0.65 }
        sub_result[:three] = tlayer_value['three']
        result << sub_result
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The value of `result` will be:

```
2.6.3 :084 > p result
[{:one=>"foo_v1_4_0", :tlayer=>"baz", :three=>0.65}, {:one=>"foo_v1_4_0", :tlayer=>"bazbar", :three=>0.65}]
```